# node.js grabbing img example?

Tags: node.js

There's an image I want to send to my server: `http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png` at `/tmp/img.png`

I understand I have to use http.get, but how sure how to do it exactly.

Can someone show me a quick example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want this example (see the answer section)?

[Node.js copy remote file to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174022/node-js-copy-remote-file-to-server)