# Is there anyway to copy/upload/edit a file with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two servers, Server1 & Server2. I want to copy a file from Server1 to Server2 with JavaScript. Is this possible? If so, how?
For example, last week I used "wget" command for this action. Now I want to handle it with JS.

Comment: You want this do be executed in a browser? Is it a text file or a binary? What server-side language is on Server2?

Comment: You could use some serverside JS solution if you really want to stick to JS for this. Node.js would be a good idea. Unless you want to run this in a browser, which does not make sense for me.

Comment: @bazmegakapa Why wouldn't it make sense? Using a web-page to provide the UI for moving files from server 1 to server 2. Seems legit.

Comment: @Mike Use AJAX to retrieve the file from Server1. Then, create a new `File` object based on the text-response (I'm not quite sure how this is done, but it should be possible), and send that file to Server2, again, via AJAX. You'll need a server-side script on Server2 to handle the file-upload and store the file.

Comment: @MikeRedford I cannot post an answer since I'm not entirely sure how a `File` would be created based on the text-response. I believe it can be done, but I'm not sure...

Comment: @MikeRedford From what I understand, to create a file/blob based on the text-response, one requires the [`BlobBuilder` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/BlobBuilder), which is currently still implemented only experimentally in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @MikeRedford Do you use a library? How would you make the AJAX-requests?

Comment: Actually I don't any idea about that, I just want to send a script to server2, but I want it be as a file, with php or js extension !

Comment: @MikeRedford Wait, you don't use *any* JavaScript library (jQuery, YUI, dojo, prototype, mootools, etc.)? How do you write JavaScript for web-pages? Vanilla JavaScript? Or are you a server-side developer?

Comment: I don't have any library, and how can I recognize vanilla or server-side? also I think it's server-side

Comment: @MikeRedford Vanilla JavaScript is when you only use the built-in APIs. Server-side JavaScript is something different, and it is not relevant here. What I meant was, are you a server-side programmer (PHP, C#, Perl, etc.)? I'm asking because you don't seem to be a front-end JavaScript programmer...

Comment: unfortunately yes, I'm java/php developer :(

Answer (score 3):

i don't know the full specifications for the task at hand, but you could look into using Node.js to assist with your issue.  here's a quick repo that might help [repo](https://github.com/felixge/node-paperboy) or you could use this snippet i took from similar post:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var google = http.createClient(80, 'www.google.com');
var request = google.request('GET', '/',
  {'host': 'www.google.com'});
 request.end();
 out = fs.createWriteStream('out');
 request.on('response', function (response) {
 response.setEncoding('utf8');
 response.on('data', function (chunk) {
  out.write(chunk);
  });
});
```

i hope this helps, and here's the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174022/node-js-copy-remote-file-to-server)

Comment: Thanks I'll check it, but where is the file for send, you know? I can't understand this code,I want to send a file with this method!

Comment: it should be the write stream, you may need to make some edits, but to answer your question - i do think that it's possible :)

Comment: @Robert I believe the OP wants the task to be executed inside the browser (with a web-page), not on a server...

Comment: @Šime Vidas that should be possible as well, and you can just instruct Node.js to execute the task or a simple web app with conventional coding can do the same; it's all on preference :)

Comment: @RobertVanSant What I mean is, your answer is not a solution, since the OP wants the task to be executed inside the browser. That's what I mean...

Comment: He said mentioned two servers, and no browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You can't access **disk** from JavaScript. Just for a moment think of security problems it can bring with itself. I simply create a web page, and when you visit it, I upload all the images of your girlfriend and publish them (just kidding, but that's the security problem it poses).

However, JavaScript can access files on some scenarios:

1. When user selects some files using `<input type='file' />` element
2. Using HTML5's offline-storage (I guess this one, not sure).

However, if you want, you can use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.5/api/fs.html#file_System) to do that. However, this is a server-side stuff.

Comment: Of course you can. Look at Node.js API http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.5/api/fs.html#file_System

Comment: @WojciechBednarski, did you vote me down? Yeah, you're right. Node.js can do that. I was only thinking of browser context. Thanks :)

Comment: @SaeedNeamati I think you misunderstood the question. The file is on the server, not on the local machine. JavaScript running in the browser may not be able to access local files, but it can access files from remote servers.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati He did not mention anything about browser, but JavaScript and server.