# Is it possible to import a script from an URL using node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm currently trying to import [one of my scripts](http://javascript-modules.googlecode.com/svn/functionChecker.js) from an URL, but the `require` function doesn't appear to be working in this case.

`var functionChecker = require("http://javascript-modules.googlecode.com/svn/functionChecker.js");`

This is an excerpt of the error message that was produced by this script:

`Error: Cannot find module 'http://javascript-modules.googlecode.com/svn/functionChecker.js'`

Is there any way to import a script from an URL in node.js?

Comment: One option would be to download the script to a local directory, and then import it just like any other module.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js

Comment: This code snippet solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4174157/975097

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to require from URL in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809397/how-to-require-from-url-in-node-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it to work. This example downloads the file http://javascript-modules.googlecode.com/svn/functionChecker.js, and then saves it in a local directory.

```
//var functionChecker = require(__dirname + '/functionChecker.js');
//functionChecker.checkAllFunctions(__filename);

var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var google = http.createClient(80, 'www.google.com');
var request = google.request('GET', '/svn/functionChecker.js',
  {'host': 'javascript-modules.googlecode.com'});
request.end();
out = fs.createWriteStream('functionChecker.js');
request.on('response', function (response) {
  response.setEncoding('utf8');
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    out.write(chunk);
  });
});

//function name: stuff
//requires functions: false
//is defined: false
//description: blah blah woohoo.
```